# Cyrillic letters using memoir and texstudio

Tags: memoir, babel, cyrillic, russian

I have typeset a book in English using `memoir`, which I find very nice for books. Now I have the Russian translation to the book and it is obviously in Cyrillic. I have tried using `babel` and different encodings to compile but the letters just show up as questions marks and it won't let me use Cyrillic letters. This is quite important as I would have to “translate” the entire book to Latin letters, which could also lead to many mistakes that I want to avoid. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}

возвращение евреев в Израиль из диаспоры (рассеяния). На иврите это слово означает «восхождение» и употребляется также при описании пути в Иерусалим, т.к. он расположен на возвышенности

\end{document}
```

I have an entire structure file for the margin specifications etc. that I won't include in this example. Not sure if this is enough though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try removing the call for `OT2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't load `OT2`, that's used for inputting Cyrillic via transliteration from Latin characters.

Rather load `T2A` (it's not really necessary, but it avoids an annoying warning).

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}

возвращение евреев в Израиль из диаспоры (рассеяния).
На иврите это слово означает «восхождение» и употребляется
также при описании пути в Иерусалим, т.к. он расположен на возвышенности

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works if I open a new tex file, but not in my original file. I copied the exact same specifications into the new file and it works fine, too. Can't really find the problem why it shows only question marks when I have the structural definitions in a separate file, it works for all other languages I have worked with. Thanks for your reply anyway, I'll just copy it into a new file and it should work with T2A :)

Comment: Interesting, for me the OPs MWE worked just fine with and without OT2.